# MongoDB updateOne() and $set:{}

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
"Department" : "PE",
"Staff" : [
    {
        "Name" : "Allen",
        "Designation" : "Application Developer",
        "Leaves" : 10
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Allen",
        "Designation" : "Product Developer",
        "Leaves" : 10
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Billy",
        "Designation" : "Product Developer",
        "Leaves" : 10
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Bob",
        "Designation" : "Application Developer",
        "Leaves" : 10
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Bob",
        "Designation" : "Product Developer",
        "Leaves" : 10
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Jim",
        "Designation" : "Application Developer",
        "Leaves" : 10
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Han",
        "Designation" : "Salesforce Developer",
        "Leaves" : 10
    }
]
}
```

I have a Document with the above structure in MongoDB. I am trying to update `Leaves` value to 15 having Designation as Application Developer and Product Developer. I tried this query

```
updateOne({'$and': [{"Department" : "PE"}, {'Staff.Name': Name}, {'Staff.Designation': Designation}]},{"$set": {'Staff.$.Leaves': 15}}, upsert=True)
```

OR

```
updateOne({"Department" : "PE", 'Staff.Name': Name, 'Staff.Designation': Designation},{"$set": {'Staff.$.Leaves': 15}}, upsert=true)
```

```
Output:
updated:2 {
            "Name" : "Allen",
            "Designation" : "Application Developer",
            "Leaves" : 15
         },
         {
            "Name" : "Allen",
            "Designation" : "Product Developer",
            "Leaves" : 15
         }
Not updated: 5
```

I tried the below queries:

```
updateOne({'$and': [{"Department" : "PE"}, {'Staff.Name': Name}, {'Staff.Designation': Designation}]},{"$set": {'Staff.$[].Leaves': 15}}, upsert=true) --> Throwing exception 
updateOne({'$and': [{"Department" : "PE"}, {'Staff.Name': Name}, {'Staff.Designation': Designation}]},{"$push": {'Staff.$.Leaves': 15}}, upsert=true)  --> Not working
updateOne({'$elemMatch': {"Department" : "PE", 'Staff.Name': Name, 'Staff.Designation': Designation}},{"$set": {'Staff.$.Leaves': 15}}, upsert=true)  --> Throwing exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), The filtered positional operator `$[<identifier>]` identifies the array elements that match the arrayFilters conditions for an update operation,

```
updateOne(
  { "Department": "PE" },
  {
    "$set": {
      "Staff.$[s].Leaves": 15
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      {
        "s.Designation": {
          $in: ["Application Developer", "Product Developer"]
        },
        "s.Name": "Allen"
      }
    ],
    upsert: true
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5DDcAKanVQH)